# Guzzle 6 - Use a .pdf generate by a .php page

Tags: php, laravel, pdf, fpdf, guzzle

I a controller which use an external page in charge of
 generating a pdf with the help of the [FPDF class](http://www.fpdf.org/).

To see if the generation is working on the server, I told to FPDF to save the file, then ask the browser to display the pdf.

Guzzle do his job, he call the page, the pdf is save and the content of the page download.

The pdf save is not corrupted and work perfectly.
The response is a pdf window showing a 'failed to load PDF document' error.

I'm using laravel, there's my controller :

```
$response = $client->request('POST','http://.../x.php', [
    'form_params' => [...]
]);

return $response;
```

Comment: Show me your complete Guzzle request..

Comment: There's only 'form_params' with some post datas, the $client is instanced by the service provider

Comment: Ok try to decode the response
$response= $response->getBody();
$result= json_decode($response);
return $result

Comment: Actually they are not in a json format, the $response is an instance of Guzzle\Response with a PSR-7 interfaces

Answer (score 0):

Laravel [doesn't use PSR-7 for `Request`/`Response`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Http/Response.php), so you have to convert Guzzle's response to Laravel's one.